# Hide/reveal content in a div using js and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to reveal content in a div by clicking on another div of an image. I have the basic idea working, but when i put content into the div it isn't hidden when the div is closed.

I put a `<ul>` in and the `<ul>` is always showing even when the div is hidden.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#header').click(function () {
    $('#content').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#content').addClass('visible');
  });
  $('#content').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#content').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
    }, 600);
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden{
    max-height: 0px;
}
.visible{
    max-height: 500px;  
}

#content{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:teal;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    transition: max-height 0.8s;
}

#header{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:darkred;
    margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `overflow:hidden` to the `hidden` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your `<ul>` is overflowing `<div>` height. Add `overflow: hidden` to `#content`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#header').click(function () {
    $('#content').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#content').addClass('visible');
  });
  $('#content').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#content').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
    }, 600);
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden{
    max-height: 0px;
}
.visible{
    max-height: 500px;  
}

#content{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:teal;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    transition: max-height 0.8s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:darkred;
    margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Add hidden class on #content div and set property `overflow:hidden;`

---

```
    .hidden{
    max-height: 0px;
    }
     .visible{
    max-height: 500px;  
    }

    #content{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:teal;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.8s;
     transition: max-height 0.8s;
     overflow:hidden;

     }

     #header{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:darkred;
    margin:10px;
    }
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#header').click(function() {

    $('#content').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#content').addClass('visible');
  });
  $('#content').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#content').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
    }, 600);
  });
});
```

---

```
 <div id="header">
    </div>
<div id="content" class="hidden">
  <ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try jquery?

Here is a jquery way in JSFiddle. But I'll post a javascript solution in a while

https://jsfiddle.net/fyws9zye/13/

```
$( "#Hideme" ).click(function() {
  $('#package').hide();
});

$( "#showme" ).click(function() {
  $('#package').show();
});
```

Comment: What if classes has other meaning than only hiding and showing elements?

Comment: Yea this is very basic as i see it, I'm improving my answer since I think it's not enough to answer the question. I'm working on it though :)

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. +1

Comment: Thanks im improving my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#header').click(function () {
$('#content').removeClass('hidden');
$('#content').addClass('visible');
$('#Hej').show();
 });
  $('#content').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
  setTimeout(function () {
  $('#content').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
    $('#Hej').hide();
  }, 600);
 });
});
```